# Azure Translation API - Throttling client requests

Tags: javascript, azure, curl, translation, throttling

I'm trying to throttle the number of requests a client can make to my translator service which uses Azure Translation API.

The following link from Microsoft describes how to limit requests, but it's not clear where in the request this throttling information should be added. I assume the request headers?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-sample-flexible-throttling

Here is the curl. Note the rate limiting headers at the end. Is this the way to do it?

```
// Pass secret key and region using headers to a custom endpoint
curl -X POST " my-ch-n.cognitiveservices.azure.com/translator/text/v3.0/translate?to=fr" \
-H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: xxx" \
-H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region: switzerlandnorth" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "rate-limit-by-key: calls=10 renewal-period=60 counter-key=1.1.1.1" \
-d "[{'Text':'Hello'}]" -v
```

Comment: Rate limiting should be done on the server. Why are you trying to make the client (curl) decide how rate limiting should be done?

Comment: I do the curl server side with PHP. I want to send the client's IP with the request in order to have Azure keep tracking of the rate limiting so I dont have to with a database. I used this example of a CURL to make it easier to see instead of using my PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

The link you've shared is from API Management, a managed API Gateway available on Azure. The idea is to generate "products" and let your users to subscribe to them. This way, you'll be able to track the requests and perform the throttle using a rate limit policy (the link you've shared).

if needed, please watch this quick video showing this functionality in use:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbF7uVkGOw0